# Geometry completion percentage slider in Group input

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm constructing a geometry node setup that joins geometry until a randomised building is formed.
Is there a way I can have a slider (from 0 to 100) in my group input that shows the completion of the building?

**Example:**

- If the building would have exactly 100 meshes and I turn the slider up to 100, the whole building would be visible. If I turn it to 20, 20% (or 20 meshes in this case) would be visible.
- If the building would have 50 meshes, 1 mesh would appear every 2 percent on the slider.

Comment: It may help to show us what you've got so far (if anything). Have you made a start with something that just joins meshes?

Comment: I've included a blend file with a basic setup.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=S8sbY3Gl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/S8sbY3Gl/)

It would be nice if the 4 poles would lay on the ground when the slider is at 0, and they would stand up when the slider is at 100.
More poles and different objects would be added so the slider would probably have to count the number of objects joined together.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick for getting sliders into the group input:  Find any node that has a slider and connect that node's slider driven input to the group input node.  Here I use a MixRGB node:

[image: Sample of how to enable a slider]

Now you can remove the node and the slider remains in the input.  To give the slider the settings you want, go to the group Inputs in the sidebar and edit the name, default, min, and max values:

[image: Group input settings]

might change to

[image: new settings]

What yo do with that slider is, of course, up to you.